# Unity IAP & Google IAP

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I live in Algeria, which is not supported in Google's Merchant account, so in my Developer Console, i can't make a Merchant account.

I tried looking in Unity forums about their list of accepted countries, but didn't find any, only thing i found was that Unity's IAP is using a Google's IAP.

Now, my question is : 
Is there a difference between Unity's IAP and Google's IAP ?

Will i be able to implement Unity's IAP, and publish my app in Play Store ?
if so, will the purchase system work ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to be able to sell IAP on the play store you're gonna have to have a Google's Merchant account. The Unity IAP simply does all the work for you so it stays simple so you don't need to do it all by yourself but you still need the Google's Merchant account.

Comment: @CNuts - That should be an answer.

Comment: @TedBigham Thanks, Added it.

Comment: accepted it :v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to sell IAP on the play store you're gonna have to have a Google's Merchant account. The Unity IAP simply does all the work for you so it stays simple so you don't need to do it all by yourself but you still need the Google's Merchant account.

From looking around the solutions I saw where to either open a bank account in a different country (I have no idea if this is legal or not) or find some company to publish your game for you.